# Problems with partitioning on GUID Partition Table

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, bios, mbr, gpt

I installed Xubuntu on my new Lenovo G580 notebook. When I tried to partition the HDD and it kept making extra 1 MB partitions at the beginning and the end and they looked like unformatted free space. I figured out it was because of the GPT system, so I looked up some things on the net, and managed to change GPT to MBR via live CD and Gparted.

After I managed to install Xubuntu, it wouldn't boot and kept throwing me back to that HUB thing where you can select the device from where you want to boot. It doesn't even get to grub, it just throws me back.
Oh, and since I installed Xubuntu, I can't enter the BIOS either.
So if I change to GPT, the BIOS comes back, but then I can't install Xubuntu, and if I change to MBR, I can't boot Xubuntu.

Please help me!

Comment: Separating partitions with a 1MB space chuncks is actually a good idea. It effectively prevents partitions from overlapping, so you might let the installer do its job.

Answer (score 1):

The "1MB partitions" you mention were probably free space, not partitions. The one at the start was there because modern partitioning tools align partitions on 1MiB boundaries, and since both MBR and GPT use some space at the start of the disk, the first partition normally begins at 1MiB, leaving a gap of a bit under 1MiB. (Note that this is true for both MBR and GPT; it's not a GPT-specific issue.) The gap at the end is likely present because the final partition was sized as a precise multiple of 1MiB, leaving a gap between its end and the end of the disk (which likely is not sized in 1MiB boundaries). Neither of these gaps is a problem, and treating them as problems to be fixed led you to create *real* problems.

So: Switch back to GPT. If you want to dual-boot with Windows, restore it. You can then install Linux. You claim that you "can't install Xubuntu" after switching back to GPT, but you provide no details of what the problem is, unless you're referring to concerns over those tiny 1MiB gaps. If that's the issue, ignore it; it's *not* a problem. If there's something else that's preventing you from installing Linux at that point, please elaborate. (Edit your original post and flag it with a comment to this one).